# как сделать background сайта полностью адаптивным?

Tags: flexbox

как сделать background сайта полностью адаптивным???

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'pt-sans';
  src: url('../fonts/pt-sans.ttf');
}

header {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1400px;
  height: 799px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)), url(../images/sunflowers.jpg);
}
```

```html
<header>



</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от изображения пути могут быть разные.

Например можно растянуть на всю видимую область блок, изображением заполнить его с обрезанием лишнего и зафиксировать.